# How to use subdomain with Rails_admin on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin, rails-administrate

I have rails admin with my application and when i try to access rails_admin by entering **localhost:3000/admin**
it generates the followibg routing error

*Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_in"*

**my device routes on routes.rb is**

require 'subdomain_constraint'

require 'domain_constraint'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

**mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'**

constraints SubdomainConstraint do

```
use_doorkeeper

root 'org_public/home#index'

devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions',
  passwords: 'users/passwords',
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Comment: It successfully accessed when i access by entering this URL

http://eritheia-labs.localhost:3000/admin

Comment: I wanna Access it by hitting this URL localhost:3000/admin instead of eritheia-labs.localhost:3000/admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SubdomainConstraint
 def self.matches?(request)
request.subdomain.present? || %w[public www].exclude?(request.subdomain)
end
end
```

This code fixed my error i just put this code in subdomain_constraint.rb file

Answer (score 0):

Your domain_constarint.rb file should be like this

```
class DomainConstraint
def self.matches?(request)
request.subdomain.blank? && %w[public www].include?(request.subdomain)
end
end
```

This code fixed error as well